# Database structure cheatsheet

Tags: database

I am trying to create a custom search page for a site I developed, but I lack the information needed to create the custom sql queries.

Are there any useful resources you guys might know of?

Comment: Just wondering ... Have you tried searching (google/codex) for 'wordpress database structure'? Doing a little research by yourself before asking can give you an instant answer (Rarst is fast, google is faster .) and help you to ask more sophisticated questions. It's also the best way to gain some reputation and help to keep the high quality of this site at the same time. No offense, enjoy this wonderful place!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Database Description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description) in Codex.

Comment: Great, thanx, thats exactly what I was looking for!